# What is taking so long?

Tags: c++, templates

I am playing a round with a lib for general purpose industrial automation. For that I need a general purpose IO class.

**IO.h**

```
template<class T> class IOImpl {}; // pimpl idiom
template<class T> class Input;

/** IO Class
 * A thread safe variable that can be reduced to a read only object
 */
template<class T>
class IO : public AbstractHMIVar
{
public:
    IO( std::string name = "" );
    IO( const IO<T> &io );
    const T value() const;
    void setValue( const T value );
    Input<T> toInput() const;
    IO<T> operator-=( const T &other );
    IO<T> operator+=( const T &other );
    IO<T> operator--();
    IO<T> operator++();
    const std::string stringval() const;
    void fromString( const std::string val );


private:
    std::shared_ptr<IOImpl<T>> pimpl_;
    std::shared_ptr<std::pair<T, std::mutex>> data;
};
```

**IO.cpp**

```
/** Default constructor
 * Create data object
 */
template<class T>
IO<T>::IO( std::string name ) : AbstractHMIVar( name ),
                                pimpl_( std::make_shared<IOImpl<T>>() ),
                                data( std::make_shared<std::pair<T, std::mutex>>() )
{
}

/** Copy constructor
 * Don't allow deep copies. Only copy the shared pointer.
 */
template<class T>
IO<T>::IO( const IO<T> &io ) : pimpl_( io.pimpl_ ), data( io.data )
{
}

/** Return the value part of data pair
 */
template<class T>
const T IO<T>::value() const
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{ data->second };

    return data->first;
}

/** Return a read only version of this object
 */
template<class T>
Input<T> IO<T>::toInput() const
{
    return Input<T>( *this );
}

template<class T>
IO<T> IO<T>::operator--()
{ 
    static_assert( std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, "Type needs to be arithmetic." );

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{ data->second };
    data->first -= 1;

    return *this;
}

template class IO<int32_t>;
```

**The problem**

I composed a little program to test the performance of this IO class.

```
for( auto i = 0; i < n_tests; i++ )
{
    IO<uint32_t> io_test( "Testvar" ); //unsigned int test
    io_test.setValue( n_iterations );  //test = n_iterations
    high_resolution_clock::time_point before = high_resolution_clock::now();
    while( io_test.value() > 0 ) //while( test > 0 )
        --io_test;               //--test

    results.push_back( duration_cast<milliseconds>( high_resolution_clock::now() - before ) );
}
```

Running 80 000 000 iterations takes 11.7 seconds.
Using a normal uint32_t without the IO class runs the same code in 0.0662 seconds.

I tried to skip the shared pointer and only using a value without shared pointer and mutex locking. But that took just as long.

I also tried different optimization levels while compiling. No difference.

Why is it taking this long?

**Edit**

I tried changing the following:

```
template<class T>
IO<T> IO<T>::operator--()
{ 
    testvar -= 1;
    return *this;
}

template<class T>
const T IO<T>::value() const
{
    return testvar;
}
```

Comment: Perchance could it be because you're locking (and unlocking) a mutex **160 000 000** times ? (once for the `value()`, once for `operator --()`). Try posting the non-IO implementation so we don't have to guess what it looks like.

Comment: Note that running your code under a decent profiler would have taken you straight to the problems in your code in a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my operator-- returned a IO which called the copy constructor every iteration. The solution was:

```
T IO<T>::operator--();
```

That was more the behaviour I wanted anyway.

Big thanks to Paul R who pushed me towards profiling tools. (Never used one before)